# Fast way to reverse float32 endianness in binary file

Tags: python, struct, binary, wav, endianness

I have a binary file, several hundred MBs in size. It contains samples in float32 big-endian format (4 bytes per sample). I want to convert them to little-endian format. Some background: I want to write them to a .wav file later on and that needs data in the little-endian format afaik.

The below code is what I currently use. It seems to work fine, but is quite slow (I assume because I am writing 4 bytes at a time only):

```
import struct

infile = "infile_big_endian.raw"
outfile = "outfile_little_endian.raw"

with open(infile, "rb") as old, open(outfile , "wb") as new:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: old.read(4), b""):
        chunk = struct.pack("<f", struct.unpack(">f", chunk)[0])
        new.write(chunk)
```

Is there a quicker way to do this in python?

Comment: You might want to skip the floating-point decode altogether. `for chunk in iter(lambda: old.read(4), b""): new.write(chunk[::-1])`

Comment: You might want to skip the reading and writing and memory-map both files.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Rob's suggestion is about x1.2 faster on my system compared to my original code (tested with a 160MB input file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy might be faster:

```
numpy.memmap(infile, dtype=numpy.int32).byteswap().tofile(outfile)
```

Or overwriting the input file:

```
numpy.memmap(infile, dtype=numpy.int32).byteswap(inplace=True).flush()
```

We memory-map the array and use [`byteswap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.byteswap.html) to reverse the endianness at C speed. I've used `int32` instead of `float32` just in case NaNs might be a problem with `float32`.

Comment: Great, thanks! This is about x46 times faster on my system compared to my original code (tested with a 160MB input file).

Comment: If I have a wave file header which I want to prepend to this memmap object and then write it to one file, how would that be done? (numpy doesn't let me prepend a bytestring to the memmap object)